# Memory leak in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4, nsautoreleasepool

I would like, given the indexPath, to get a reference to the related cell to remove the checkmark. I thought I could use the cellForRowAtIndexPath for this, but I get the message:

__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x685a600 of class UITableView autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

even for a simple line like this:

```
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

So, this is not only returning a pointer to a cell, right? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what this method is for. Is it possible to simply get a reference to a cell to change the accessoryView?
Thanks!

Comment: Could we see some more of your code (e.g. what you're using to remove the accessory item)? Hard to tell anything from a single innocuous line...

Comment: Yes, I was performing the selector in the background. I didn't know an autorelease was sent to the returned value. I really don't remember I read this in the memory management guide. I must have missed it. But thanks for pointing this important thing out! I just created a NSAutoreleasePool and everything is correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error: `_NSAutoreleaseNoPool()` is generally related to exactly this - not having an Auto release pool in place. Autoreleasepools are thread-based, so if you are executing this in the background or on another thread (hard to tell from this little code) you'll need to create an NSAutoreleasPool in that thread and release it after you're done with your execution.

Comment: This was in fact the problem... but why did I need an autorelease pool? Does cellForRowAtIndexPath: allocate any data? Doesn't it only return a pointer to an already existing cell? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your error message shows that UITableView is leaking. Joe Blow points it out correctly below, the (implicit) getter is the problem. By convention, the return values of getters are autoreleased. So just self.tableView; on a line by itself will leak if you don't have an autoreleasepool. In contrast to @Joe Blum below tho, i wouldn't recommend forgetting about getter, but rahter just having autoreleasepools.

Comment: @Joe: Besides in the setter and getter themselves, when would you not use the property?